# C#: Async Task: Cancel

Tags: c#, cancellation

I have an function that does some work for a few seconds. I'm trying to cancel that task after a certain time period and am unable to do so. My objective is to do the asyncFunction for 5 seconds and then, move onto to a different task. For some reason, I can't seem to await _t1.

```
private async Task asyncFunction(string line_1, string line_2, string line_3, string line_4, int _time, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource _cts)
    {
        _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await Task.Run(async () => {
            someFunction_01(line_1, line_2, line_3, line_4);                
            someFunction_01("HELLO WORLD");
            await Task.Delay(_time, _cts.Token);
        });
    }
```

The way I'm calling my funcion is:

```
TimeSpan _timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource(_timeout);
            
            Task _t1 = asyncFunction("LINE 01", " ", " ", " ", 6000, timeoutCancellationTokenSource);
if (await Task.WhenAny(_t1, Task.Delay(_timeout, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token)) == _t1)
            {                    
                await _t1;
            }
            else
            {
                // timeout/cancellation logic                    
                timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
```

I can't seem to cancel the Task.Delay inside of the asyncFunction. Any code help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the purpose of the code. Particulary the if-statement:

```
if (await Task.WhenAny(_t1, Task.Delay(_timeout, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token)) == _t1)
```

Why pass in a `_timeout` to `Task.Delay` which is the same timeout as you created the `timeoutCancellationTokenSource` with?

If we ignore the first parameter you give `Task.Delay` it also means you have two calls to `Task.Delay` with the same `CancellationToken` and now you have a race-condition where it's impossible to predict which `Task.Delay` will be cancelled first.

---

To show an example of how you can get the cancellation to work, you can do like this:

```
TimeSpan _timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource(_timeout);

Task _t1 = asyncFunction("LINE 01", " ", " ", " ", 2000, timeoutCancellationTokenSource);
try
{
    await _t1;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Operation was cancelled");
}

// Output: Operation was cancelled
```

If `_timeout` is longer than the `2000` milliseconds passed into `asyncFunction` the task completes after 2 seconds without being cancelled.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UQwhc7) for a test run.

Comment: instead of asyncFunction can you use a simple method which prints hello world and await Delay(2000);

Comment: @user1735921 Yea, definitely. Although, it's not clear to me what the purpose of the `Task.Delay` is.